# Display PDF Takes Focus and Eats Hot Key

Tags: .net, wpf, pdf, windowsformshost

Used code I found on SO to use the COM based Acrobat Reader to display PDF via hosting in a WindowsFormsHost.

It displays the PDF fine.  Two problems:

- When I load the PDF the control AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF takes focus

  I want focus to remain on the prior
- When AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF has focus it eats the Hot Key (N)

  The ALT key does not even underline the N.  Even if the user selects the AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF I would like the Hot Keys to work.

I understand this is COM and Adobe in WPF and there may not be an answer.  If there is a free or cheap WPF control to view PDF I would be happy to go down that path.  This is for a commercial application so it has to be free (or cheap) for commercial use.

```
 <Button  Click="Button_Click">_Next</Button>     

 <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1"  Margin="1" />
```

```cs
 UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1(@"C:\temp\1000001.pdf");
 this.windowsFormsHost1.Child = UC;


 public UserControl1(string filename)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
 }
```

This does display PDF.   In the production application I display various PDFs based on used actions.

Comment: Acrobat Reader uses a nasty hack, the control is actually a window owned by another process (AcroRd32.exe).  That has all kind of side effects, eating keystrokes is just one of them.  Not sure it matters, users are kinda familiar with the Adobe software annoyances.

Comment: Oh yes I am painfully aware that Adobe does not play well even in COM and this is COM in WPF.  Even a key down event on the windowsFormsHost1 down not fire.  XPS does play well.  I would convert to XPS on the fly but this is for a litigation support application and because of chain of custody I must display THE pdf.  I could just launch a native process so the problems are external but that is still problematic and a disjointed UI.

Comment: Are you willing to consider other third party PDF viewer components?

Comment: If so, we've had fairly good success at getting O2S's PDFView4Net working fairly quickly (http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm). Note: Is a licensed and I've only used the WinForms component but they look to have WPF specific component too.

Comment: It looks like the O2S renders the PDF to an image.   Not sure that will satisfy our chain of custody restriction but I will check.  The pricing seems reasonable.

Comment: @HansPassant if you will post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'll take a pass on this one.  You can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Hans said.  Acrobat appears to be eating key strokes and there is nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if it fits the needs of anyone reading this: I just found a way around my version of this problem (got a textbox for inputs and want it to regain focus after loading a pdf with AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF).

My solution was this:

```
        private void returnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Focus();
    }

        this.textBox.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.returnFocus);
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I freaked out finding this neat code which works great with the TimeSpan adjusted a bit!

bertvansteen/AxAcroPDFFocusExtensions.cs

https://gist.github.com/bertvansteen/ec180b645fd6bcfd179e/04647563701764d498f77022b6f2b77b04ca18cb

```
/// <summary>
/// Extensions for the Acrobat ActiveX control
/// /* Copyright (c) 2014 Bert Van Steen */
/// <example>
///    axAcroPDF1.SuspendStealFocus(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
///    axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(scanFilename);
/// </example>
/// </summary>
static class AxAcroPDFFocusExtensions
{
   struct TimerTag
   {
      public TimerTag(AxAcroPDF control, object controlTag)
      {
         Control = control;
         ControlTag = controlTag;
      }

      public object ControlTag;
      public AxAcroPDF Control;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Prevent Adobe AxAcroPDF from stealing focus when you change the src. 
   /// The control will be disabled for 250 ms
   /// /// <param name="pdfControl">The acrobat ActiveX control</param>
   /// </summary>
   public static void SuspendStealFocus(this AxAcroPDF pdfControl)
   {
      SuspendStealFocus(pdfControl, 250);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Prevent Adobe AxAcroPDF from stealing focus when you change the src. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="pdfControl">The acrobat ActiveX control</param>
   /// <param name="timeSpan">Time the ActiveX will be inaccessible (and 
       not grabbing focus)</param>
   public static void SuspendStealFocus(this AxAcroPDF pdfControl, TimeSpan 
   timeSpan)
   {
      SuspendStealFocus(pdfControl, (int)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Prevent Adobe AxAcroPDF from stealing focus when you change the src. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="pdfControl">The acrobat ActiveX control</param>
   //// <param name="timeoutInMilliSeconds">Number of milliseconds the 
     ActiveX will be inaccessible (and not grabbing focus)</param>
   public static void SuspendStealFocus(this AxAcroPDF pdfControl, int 
    timeoutInMilliSeconds)
   {
      pdfControl.Enabled = false;
   
      Timer t = new Timer();
      t.Interval = timeoutInMilliSeconds;
      t.Tick += t_Tick;
      t.Start();

      pdfControl.Tag = Guid.NewGuid();
      t.Tag = new TimerTag(pdfControl, pdfControl.Tag);
   }
  
   static void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var timer = (Timer)sender;
      timer.Stop();
      timer.Dispose();

      TimerTag t = (TimerTag) timer.Tag;
      if (ReferenceEquals(t.Control.Tag, t.ControlTag))
      {
         t.Control.Enabled = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my hacked solution for dealing with this is add a delay before enabling the panel. 
Obviously you want to add the minimum delay possible but too little and with the wrong file it will nick the focus again.

```
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    Panel1.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If Me.AxAcroPDF1.ContainsFocus = True Then
      Me.TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically '.ContainsFocus' becomes True once the PDF document is loaded. Monitor this value in a quick timer (~200ms), and reFocus to another control if needed.  Not Ideal, but it works reliably.