# Trouble with setting focus/select to Form1 after I show Form2 using AxAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, winforms, select, focus, form-control

As per title, I am having trouble selecting and setting focus to a control in Form1 right after I show Form2. Any idea why the below code is not working?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
     public Form2 frm2;

     ...

     public void ReadThroughContents(int index)
     {
        ...

        if (frm2.IsDisposed || frm2 == null) { frm2 = new Form2(); }
        if (!frm2.Visible) { frm2.Show(); }

        this.listbox1.Focus();
        this.listbox1.Select();

        ...
     }
```

EDIT: Just to make it clear, the focus stays on Form2. I am however able to select and focus on Form1 manually by clicking on the form, but I need this to be done automatically.

EDIT: In Form2 I am using the `AxAcroPDFLib` library. A PDF file is loaded in Form2 when it is shown. I believe that this is what is preventing Form1 to get focus. I have tried without loading the PDF file and I can automate focus.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to @defaultlocale above!

Code copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996191/display-pdf-takes-focus-and-eats-hot-key)

```
private void returnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstboxItems.Focus();
    }
this.lstboxItems.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.returnFocus);
```

Answer (score 1):

> > Just to make it clear, the focus stays on Form2.

This happens because `Form.Show` steals the focus.

You may try to bring focus back to Form1 before setting focus to specific controls. You can use [Form.Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this:

```
//...
this.Activate();
this.listbox1.Focus();
//...
```

Check out this quesiton if you want to always show Form2 without stealing focus: [Show a Form without stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus)

Comment: This would work without me using AxAcroPDFLib... I believe that my problem is much more complicated. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: @TonyMontana I have no experience with Acrobat SDK. Search bring me to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996191/display-pdf-takes-focus-and-eats-hot-key), take a look on Hans Passant's comment there